# App fails to launch in Android gingerbread v2.3.6

Tags: android, android-logcat

My app works fine in Marshmallow and Lollipop versions. But fails to launch in Gingerbread.

This is the error logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime(23029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate application
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hub.hubcrm-1.apk]
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23029): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hub.hubcrm-1.apk]
>   W/ActivityManager(  295):   Force finishing activity
>   com.convergehub.convergehubcrm/.MainActivity

This is my manifest

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LeadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lead"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        </activity>

    </application>
```

Here is my MainActivity oncreate code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("CHub","Main Activity Started");
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        if (isNetworkAvailable(this))
        {
            Log.d("CHub","Network Available ");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Hub","Network Unavailable");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network unavailable.App will close.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();
        }



        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
            {
                Log.d("CHub","Already permitted");

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("CHub","Need permission");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            }
        }
        if(MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.d("CHub","PERMISSION_GRANTED");
            tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("CHub","PERMISSION_DENIED");
        }

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/");

    }
```

The minimum SDK version is set to 9 and target SDK version is 23. And build tools version is 23.0.3 in the gradle settings.

Why does my app fail to start in the Gingerbread version?